# Error: Message failed: 553 Relaying disallowed as @ . - NodeMail Zoho

Tags: zoho

After searching for more than 6 hours trying to understand what is zoho's mail problem to send emails!
After i read lots of their answer with no helpful solution, i found the solution is that you need to have the `sender` option
in your NodeMailer option same like email with same sender name and sender email. like this :  `from: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne<emailname@yourwebsite.com>',`

my config :

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'Zoho',
        host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        auth: {
          user: `${process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS}`,
          pass: `${process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD}`
        },
      });
    
      const mailOptions = {
        from: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne" <emailname@yourwebsite.com>',
        to: `${user.email}`,
        subject: '',
        text:''
         ,
      };

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('there was an error: ', err);
          res.status(401).json(err);
        } else {
          // console.log('here is the res: ', response);
          res.status(200).json('recovery email sent');
        }
      });
```

hopefully it helps someone

Comment: @Edwinner what was the answer

Comment: It needs a `from` on the email i.e `from: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne<emailname@yourwebsite.com>'`

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. Silly of me, how could I forget! +1

Comment: Thanks, that really saved me time!

Comment: Thanks so much, Mr.heshamelmasry99 for sharing useful information. I also struggle to get understanding why it's working with gmail but not with zoho. It helps me a lot thanks for sharing with us.

Comment: thanks for saves me 6 hours!

Answer (score 2):

This helped me a lot.
And to be more specific,

The cause of my error was that the emailname@yourwebsite.com was missing from "from: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne" emailname@yourwebsite.com'". Immediately I added it, it worked perfectly.
Thanks a lot for the clarification

Comment: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne<emailname@yourwebsite.com>' I meant

Answer (score 0):

I spent full night on this !
In my case the email was successfully sent using this command

```
echo "test-body" | mailx -r senderEamil@tld.com -s "test-subject" reciverEmail@tld.com
```

But this was not working

```
echo "test-body" | mailx -s "test-subject" reciverEmail@tld.com
```

So found that my website is using the host VM user name where it wasn't the same of the sender email smtp config in my postfix

I had two solution

1. To explictily set a sender username to the postfix [check this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473643)
2. Add a user name similar to the sender email at your VM