# Error: Message failed: Relaying disallowed @ . -C# MailKit Zoho

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, mailkit, zoho

with the help of following links

[Error: Message failed: 553 Relaying disallowed as @ . - NodeMail Zoho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738924/error-message-failed-553-relaying-disallowed-as-nodemail-zoho)

https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/hi-i-have-an-error-code-553

I found that my code was missing From tag in email sending, and due to which I was getting error Relaying Disallowed @.

I was using .NET 6 Api to send Email using #mailkit. Earlier I was using M365 for sending email and it was working fine and From Tag was not required in the code. But then I have shifted to Zoho mail and we started getting relaying Disallowed @ error. With the help of link mentioned above I found that from tag is required. I tried to add from tag like mentioned in the link `'"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne<emailname@yourwebsite.com>'` and also tried like this  `"from: '"senderNameSameLikeTheZohoOne" emailname@yourwebsite.com'".` First approach gave resulted the same as Relaying Disallowed @ and 2nd approach gave the exception  of Invalid parse token on MimeMessage mailkit.

Answer (score 0):

In last I noticed I am missing From tag in the following code. Because as I mentioned I was using M365 Email to send emails and it was working fine. But for #Zoho I need to add this from tag in my code.

> email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(request.From
> ??_mailSettings.EmailFrom));

```
                var email = new MimeMessage();
                email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(request.From ?? _mailSettings.EmailFrom);
                email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(request.From ??_mailSettings.EmailFrom));

                email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(request.To));
                email.Subject = request.Subject;
                var builder = new BodyBuilder();
                builder.HtmlBody = request.Body;
                email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
                using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                //smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.SmtpHost, _mailSettings.SmtpPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.SmtpHost, _mailSettings.SmtpPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.SmtpUser, _mailSettings.SmtpPass);
                await smtp.SendAsync(email);
                smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

I hope this helps to the people using mailkit and C#.